# Unable to invoke AWS Lambda function on iOS - AWSLambdaInvoker invokeFunction method blocks indefinitely

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm looking to execute a Lambda function on an iOS app. I have done so successfully with another project using the Swift 2 version using the older syntax:

```
let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.defaultLambdaInvoker()    
lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction(functionArn, JSONObject: parameters).continueWithBlock
```

Since starting with the Swift 3 syntax on a new project, I haven't managed to execute a Lambda function successfully. This is my code:

```
print("START")
let functionName = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789101:function:FunctionName:REL1"
let payload = [
  "FirebaseId": User.shared.firebaseId!,
  "FacebookAccessToken": FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
]
let invoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()
invoker.invokeFunction(functionName, jsonObject: payload).continue(successBlock: {
  (task) -> Any? in
  print("yay!")
  print("task \(task)")
  return nil
})
print("END")
```

These are my outputs:

```
START
2016-11-02 20:40:29.143741 ABC App[736:208570] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-11-02 20:40:29.152692 ABC App[736:208570] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

As you can see, the execution blocks at "invoker.invokeFunction" indefinitely. The app doesn't hang nor terminate. I'm able to interact with other parts of the app without issues. I do not see "END" in my console output, nor any of the text that's printed in successBlock.

The Cognito Identity Pool has access to the Lambda function, and it has been tested with the Policy Simulator in AWS.

Login to Facebook and Cognito are successful. The block of code above are executed in the completion block of a successful Cognito login. I'm able to read both the Facebook Access Token and Cognito to ascertain that I've logged in successfully.

Does anyone know the issue with this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are invoking the Lambda function with the right credentials? Just adding the tokens to the payload does not do this.

Comment: I'm not looking to authenticate with the payload. Those are inputs. I have already authenticated with Cognito, and am able to read Cognito IDs.

Comment: Have updated inputs to prevent confusion. Thanks @Digitalkapitaen

Comment: Resolved: providing the Facebook access token in the payload (i.e. FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString) actually causes the function call to block indefinitely. Didn't dig too much into it. Likely, it's caused by some circular referencing of pointers to the token.